# Foreign key constraint error in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, orm, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have three entities which look like this:

```
@Entity
class EntityA{       
    @OneToMany(cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<EntityB> _candidates = null;
}

@Entity
class EntityB{       
   @OneToOne
   private EntityC _comp;
}

@Entity
class EntityC{
...
}
```

`EntityB` has a property of type `EntityC`. When an instance `instanceC` of `EntityC` is deleted, all the instances `instancesB` of `EntityB` referencing it must be deleted as well, from the instances of `EntityA` containing the `instancesB`.

Can I achieve this behavior through annotations? In the current state of the code, when deleting an `EntityC` object I get the following exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: I think you need to define more relationships.  You should add a `@ManyToOne` relationship in `EntityB` that references `EntityA`.  You should also add a `@OneToOne` to `EntityC` that references `EntityB`.  Then you can add `CascadeType` attributes to all your relationships.

Comment: Hi @jahroy, thanks for the reply! This approach doesn't seem to work. I get the same type of error. Isn't there a problem that both `EntityA` and `EntityC` reference `EntityB`? I cannot delete `A` or `C` without a foreign key constraint failing.

Comment: If `B` contains a `C`, you can't delete the `C` until the `B` is deleted.  That's just how foreign keys work... I'm not sure you can change that by using annotations.  Also, I don't know if you would want to.  I think you need to write some business logic to manage your relationships.  All this being said, I don't think I'm enough of an expert to give you authoritative advice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your B table has foreign keys to both A and C with your current mappings which must be maintained.  Because the fk to A is controlled by A's OneToMany to B, this one wont be too much of a problem as long as you remove A's reference to B when you delete B, just to keep your cached entities in sync the the changes.   The relation to C on the other hand requires you to dereference C from B before it can be deleted, that or delete B as well- otherwise the fk in the B table will remain, violating the constraint.  As the comments state, you will need some level of relationship management when removing entities.

Comment: I believe it is a common practice to maintain these relationships in the methods of a stateless session bean (if you're using EJB).